# How to connect azure datatable using query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I want to fetch data from Azure SQL database and display it on my locally hosted SQL server. 
I don't want to connect through database engine, I just want to use azure tables and its data in my locally hosted database. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: You need to connect to your Azure instance before you can feetch data to your local host.

Comment: Can I do it without connecting instance?

Comment: How would you query data if your not connected?